# How to get callinfo back in common API callback function

Tags: c++, c++11, dbus

I have middleware service built on token mechanism for client server communication. Now we are porting from DBus to Common API. And we want to retain framework built on token mechanism. But in the Common API, for all async calls we wont get token back in the callback.

I want to call a function like

```
CommonAPI::CallStatus getAudio(int arg1, int arg 2, Callback,const CommonAPI::CallInfo)
```

Callback is of type -

```
void Callback(const CommonAPI::CallStatus& status, int & id, int error& errorVal);
```

My Question:
In the callback there is no CallInfo param which i had sent while calling getAudio function. Could someone help me on how to get callInfo from callback ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can pass your token in the CallInfo structure. Anyway, whatever is the object you want to pass to the callback, you could use, for example, **std::function** for this purpose. I believe that a lambda expression could do the job too.

In the following example, I describe a possible way to pass a CallInfo object (but the code could be adapted to any class) to a CommonAPI callback.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;

class CallbackHelper {
 public:
  explicit CallbackHelper(CallInfo& callinfo_) :
    _callinfo(callinfo_) {
  }
  void callback(const CommonAPI::CallStatus& status, int & id, int, error& errorVal) {
    // Do whatever with _callinfo
  }
 private:
  CallbackHelper() = default;
};

CallInfo callInfo;
CallbackHelper myCallback(callInfo);

std::function<void(const CommonAPI::CallStatus& status, int & id, int, error& errorVal)> callback = std::bind(&CallbackHelper::callback, &myCallback, _1, _2, _3, _4);

getAudio(1, 2, callback, callInfo);
```

Just be sure that myCallback object is still alive when the callback is effectivelly triggered...